# spring batch NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have developed a spring batch for loading users into a DB. I am able to run it as a Java Application from eclipse providing the main class but not able to run the batch by a shell script on a unix server. I get this exception:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jobLauncher' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
at com.batch.LoadBatch.launchJob(LoadBatch.java:56)
at com.batch.LoadBatch.main(LoadBatch.java:38)
```

I have my beans declared in a job.xml file as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd"">

<bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>classpath:LoadBatch.properties </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

    <!--
        *****************************productLoadJob********************************
    -->

    <bean id="completionPolicy" class="org.springframework.batch.repeat.policy.DefaultResultCompletionPolicy"/> 

    <bean id="multiResourceReader"
        class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="resources" value="file:///${inputFilePath}*.csv" />
        <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemReader" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="flatFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean class="com.mapper.IndividualRetailerFieldSetMapper" />
                </property>
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="delimiter" value="," />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="flatFileItemWriter" 
          class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
        <property name="resource" value="file:${outputFilePath}${outputFileName}.${outputFileType}" />
        <property name="appendAllowed" value="true" />
        <property name="lineAggregator">
          <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value="," />
            <property name="fieldExtractor">
                <bean   
                  class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <property name="names" value="serialNo,mobileNo,role,parentId" />
                </bean>
            </property>
          </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.handlers.LoadWriter" scope="step">
        <property name="LoadFileHandler" ref="filehandler" />       
        <property name="LoadFieldSetMapper" ref="LoadFieldSetMapper"/>
        <property name="opId" value="ABC" />
        <property name="buId" value="XYZ" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="batchExceptionListner" class="com.handlers.LoadBatchExceptionListener" >
        <property name="irLoadFileHandler" ref="filehandler" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="filehandler" class="com.handlers.IRLoadFileHandler" />
    <bean id="IRLoadFieldSetMapper" class="com.handlers.IRLoadFieldSetMapper" />
    <bean id="skipExceptionListner" class="com.handlers.IRLoadSkipExceptionListener" />


    <batch:job id="IRLoadJob">
        <batch:step id="importFileStep">
            <batch:tasklet>
               <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="flatFileItemWriter"
                            processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="1">
               </batch:chunk>               
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="batchExceptionListner" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:job>
</beans>
```

Adding the context initialization code here:

```
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"classpath*:Job.xml"});
        logger.info("context in Spring Initializer is :: " + context.getBeanDefinitionCount());
```

Comment: Looks like when you run it through shell script, the spring application context is not initializing the beans defined in your xml file, possible reason could be that the xml file does not exist where it is supposed to be. Use an acrhive tool like win rar and check if this file exists at the correct path.

Comment: Please check in your LoadBatch whether the context is being initialized properly. How are you initializing context ?

Comment: @varun i put a logger at the getContext method and i am able to get an ApplicationContext object in the log.

Comment: @ArunM When i log the bean DefinitionCount it prints 0. I have added the context initialization code from my java file in the question.

Comment: Hmm ... Please can you enable spring debug logs and check whats happening . In case you need help, http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/114657-how-to-enable-spring-log4j-debugging

Comment: The problem for you is that the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext is not able to find the XML ? How have you packaged your application,Is it a JAR ? Are you setting classpath correctly.

Comment: Yes Arun I have packaged my batch in a jar using the maven build. I am setting the classpath correctly, As I can load the property file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the properties and xml files in 2 locations, namely inside my batch jar as well as the location on the server from where i had configured the batch. Iremoved the files from the inside of my jar and my batch started running! :)